# How to increase sd card memory in android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, android-sdcard

This question may be silly but my doubt is, If increase sd card size in the AVD, will I lose the previous data  that I have stored?

This is happening because I started with 50 mb as external storage but now I need more space and I don't want to lose the previous data

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Window menu -> Android Virtual Device Manager -> Select your AVD -> click on Edit option on right side -> In that change the size of SD card as you want

Comment: Ok I know this, My question is. Will I lose my previous data?

Comment: if you don't see it you can expand that edit window vertically, time wasted lol!